# Convergence of an integral involving tan function

Tags: improper-integrals

How would i prove that integral $$\int_0^{1}{\frac{\tan^2(x)}{\sqrt{x^5}}}$$ converges?
By using some plotting apps, I managed to find that $\tan^2(x) \le 3x^2$ for $x \in (0, 1)$ (which would complete the proof easily) but I have no clue how to prove such inequality without computerized help.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When $x \sim 0$, the integrand behaves as ${1 \over x^{1/2}}$ which is an integrable singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following approach: $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ and $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^2$ are bounded differentiable functions over $[0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable over $(0,1)$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^2$ is for sure integrable over $(0,1)$.

For an explicit bound, you may show that $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ is positive and increasing over $\left(0,1\right)$ by the convexity of the tangent function, hence:

> $$\color{red}{0}\leq \color{purple}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^2\,dx} \leq \tan^2(1)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=\color{red}{2\tan^2(1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor expansion around zero
$$\tan(x)=x+\mathcal{o}(x),$$
thus 
$$\tan^2(x)=x^2+\mathcal{o}(x).$$
So your function around $0$ looks like
$$x^{-1/2}$$
which is clearly integrable.